# Java JAR file does not execute in startup script in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, bash

The following process normally works for my startup scripts.  However, when I introduce a command to execute a JAR file, it does not work.  This script works while I am logged in.  However, it does not work as a startup script.

1. In /etc/init.d I create a bash script (test.sh) with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   pw=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

   pwh=$(/usr/bin/java -jar PWH.jar $pw &) 

   echo $pwh > test.txt
   ```
2. Make script executable
3. In /etc/rc.local, I add the following line:

   ```
   sh /etc/init.d/test.sh
   ```

Notes:

1. I make a reference to the script in /etc/rc.local, because this script needs to run last after all services have started.
2. Please do not ask me to change the process (i.e., create script in /etc/init.d/ and reference it from /etc/rc.local), because it works for my other startup scripts.
3. I have tried adding nohup in front of java command, and it still did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, there is insufficient information to say what is going wrong.  There are too many possibilities to enumerate.

Try running those commands one at a time in an interactive shell.  The `java` command is probably writing something to standard error, and that will give you some clues.

Comment: The script works fine in an interactive shell.  It just doesn't work during startup.

Comment: Fine ... so change the startup script to capture the output so that you can see what it says in that context.  Also, capture the commands that are being executed - use "set -x".  You have not provided enough context to allow someone else to say what is going on.  Unless you provide more info, only you can debug it.

Comment: *"Please do not ask me to change the process (i.e., create script in /etc/init.d/ and reference it from /etc/rc.local), because it works for my other startup scripts"* -  It is up to you.  But if you aren't prepared to do that, I doubt that you are ever going to solve your problem!!

Comment: Additional context.  I just reran it one line at a time and I see my problem.  My goal was to redirect the java command to the variable pwh.   The java command is not redirecting the output to the variable pwh.  I am going to try to redirect the java output to a file, and then run a grep and cut on the file to store the contents in the variable.